# EF Core Invalid Column Name (Foreign Keys)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2
the Code with the error

```
var ClientCase= _context.Client_Cases.Include(a=>a.Case_Sessions). FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

The Error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:  'Invalid column name
> 'Client_CaseId'. Invalid column name 'Case_LevelId'. Invalid column
> name 'Client_CaseId'. Invalid column name 'Court_CircleId'. Invalid
> column name 'Court_HallId'.'

Entities

1- Parent Client_Case

```
public class Client_Cases
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }        
    public string Opponent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Recieve_Date { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Clients")]
    public long? ClientID { get;set;}
    public Clients Client { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Case_Levels")]
    public long? LevelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Case_Levels Case_Levels { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Case_Types")]
    public long? TypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Case_Types Case_Types { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Court_Circles")]
    public long? CircleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Court_Circles Court_Circles { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Court_Halls")]
    public long? HallID { get; set; }
    public virtual Court_Halls Court_Halls { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Courts")]
    public long? CourtID { get; set; }
    public virtual Courts Court { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Case_Status")]
    public long? StatusID { get; set; }
    public Case_Status Case_Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Lawyers")]
    public long? LawyerID { get; set; }
    public virtual LawyersData Lawyers { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CaseNo { get; set; }
    public List<Case_Sessions> Case_Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Detail Entity Case_Session

```
public class Case_Sessions
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }        
    [ForeignKey("Client_Cases")]
    public long? CaseID { get;set;}
    public Client_Cases Client_Case { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Case_Levels")]
    public long? LevelID { get; set; }
    public Case_Levels Case_Level { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Court_Circles")]
    public long? CircleID { get; set; }
    public Court_Circles Court_Circle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Court_Halls")]
    public long? HallID { get; set; }
    public Court_Halls Court_Hall { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Case_Status")]
    public long? StatusID { get; set; }
    public Case_Status Case_Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Session_Date { get; set; }
    public string Judge_Name { get; set; }
    public string Session_Result { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

If I get the parent without including the child it works.
If I get the details, it works.

I know the error that EF Core Create its own naming convention for the Foreign keys
but I think the tag Foreign Key override that naming convention

Now where I am wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ForeignKey("")] Mean? name the property you have added in class to become a foreign key. e.g:

```
public long? CaseID { get;set;}
[ForeignKey("CaseID")]
public Client_Cases Client_Case { get; set; }

public long? CircleID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CircleID")]
public Court_Circles Court_Circle { get; set; }
```

You can use annotations like above, In your case, below correction needed:

```
[ForeignKey("Client")] // it should be [ForeignKey("Client")] not an extra s if you using entities name in annotation.
    public long? ClientID { get;set;}
    public Clients Client { get; set; }
```

this should be your relationship for lawyer:

```
[ForeignKey("Lawyers")]
    public long? LawyersID { get; set; }
    public virtual LawyersData Lawyers { get; set; }
```

I am assuming that the type of primary key in LawyersData table is long?.

Comment: you mean [ForeignKey("Case_Status")] take the name for the column  not the name of the table ?? but i'm putting the name of the table in the data annotation and it is working on other places

Comment: yes, name for the column, but they can take entity name too.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx check this link.

Comment: Now i'm confused in the begining you are writing the column name then you are writing the table name

Comment: Both works, The way you did is slightly wrong. You use like: [ForeignKey("Clients")], it should be Client not clients. so correct one is: [ForeignKey("Client")]

Comment: *name: Name of the associated navigation property or the name of the associated foreign key(s)* `ForeignKey` is one of the most confusing attributes. Depending on where it is applied, it could be one or another, but **never* the entity name.

Comment: what about  [ForeignKey("HallID")]
         
        public virtual Court_Halls Court_Halls { get; set; } will the column be generated with that name ?? do i have to write  public long? HallID{ get; set; }

Comment: Yes, you have to write: public long? HallID{ get; set; } with the same name as you are using in the annotation. Make sure the type of HallID is the same type as the foreign table's primary key.

Comment: Last Question   [ForeignKey("Court_Circles")]
        public long? CircleID { get; set; }
        public Court_Circles Court_Circle { get; set; } i'm writing the table name in the last line should i write  Court_Circles (the blue) or Court_Circle  (the name i wrote)

Comment: [ForeignKey("LawyersData")]
        public long? LawyerID { get; set; }
        public virtual LawyersData Lawyers { get; set; } it is giving error invalid column name LawyersID

Comment: i tried that too  [ForeignKey("LawyerID")]
        public long? LawyerID { get; set; }
        public virtual LawyersData Lawyers { get; set; } still the same error  invalid column name LawyersID

Comment: find the modified answer above.